# CSS media queries ( media screen )

Tags: html, css, wordpress, media-queries, screen-size

I have the following queries on my WordPress theme, and they are alot ;/

I am new to WordPress so i can't understand them correctly, but i am sure i will understand your explanation .

here is what I don't understand.

1: I don't understand for which screen's they are.

2: I don't understand what the "max" ( **this one is very strange** )

3: will the max width terminate the setting or something ? because we have min 600 and max 600

here is the code.

[image]

Comment: It's very bad practice to include screenshots of your code. Please copy & paste this so we can poke around in general.

Comment: Read this https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1)** `screen` here means the screen of the device itself (not a `print` as `print` is the common one). But this has same effect as

```
@media (min-width: 312px)
```

Just you are specifying that you want the `max-width` of the `screen` on that the website loaded, that's it

**2)** the `max` means the maximum width of the device screen to which the following styles are applied.

for eg:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
  //These styles will apply only if the screen size is less than or equal to 768px
}
```

**3)** There is no termination. If you have `max` and `min` with `600px`, then the styles will applied as per the position of the code. The code that comes below will apply (if `min` code is at line number 10 and `max` code at line number 20 then `max` will work)

Comment: i have samsung tab 4 , and it's resolution should be 1280 x 800 . 
but when i search at google for what is my resolution i get 900 x something

Comment: @abdorefky This is the difference between `device pixel` and `css pixel`.  

which crams two(or three or more) device pixels into each CSS pixel on the screen. 

for device pixel a device can divide 10cm width into 900px or for more clarity devices it can be 1240px or more. But the actual width in centi meters is same (10cm). `css pixel` is like device width in `cm`, its will be a measure like `cm` or `mm` etc. 

`1cm = 37.795276px`

Comment: english please :D

Comment: @abdorefky This is the difference between `device pixel` and `css pixel`.  

which crams two(or three or more) device pixels into each CSS pixel on the screen. 

for `device pixel`, a device can divide 10cm width into 900px or for devices with more clarity can be 1240px or more. But the actual width in centi meters is same (10cm). `css pixel` is like device width in `cm`, its will be a measure like `cm` or `mm` etc. 

`1cm = 37.795276px`

Comment: It was English only. But unfortunately missed some full stops

Comment: if i have 2 screens and both of them are 10CM. but one is 1600px and the other is 900px. then CSS will ignore the 1600 & the 900 and will calculate his own by 10 X 37.795276 = 377 pix . and then it will apply the the setting that apply for 377 pix

Comment: @abdorefky absolutely. have a look at **[here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml)**

Comment: Great. this point and the line order point are the core. 
now i will able to know what i am doing :D. 
those 2 points made you deserve the correct answer.

Comment: Go ahead :) media query is very interesting. But before that google adaptive vs responsive webdesign. You will get more information

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122221/discussion-between-abdo-refky-and-syam-pillai).

Comment: thanks, strange people keep giving me negative !

Comment: would like to help with this ?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39256080/css-media-screen-1-pixel-with-huge-issue?noredirect=1#comment65848669_39256080

Answer (score 2):

Screens are not printed on paper or read out through a speaker. They are screens like the ones on a smartphone, laptop or monitor, and the rules apply to all of them (which also meet the `and` condition).

Max is a standard English term. The rules apply unless the width is more than the maximum defined. It won't terminate anything, the rules inside it just apply when the condition is met.

> because we have min 600 and max 600

… with different sets of rules. Some apply when the width is at least 600px and some apply when it is no more than 600px.

Comment: could you vote to my question please ?

Answer (score 2):

With mediaqueries you can determine on which resolution your styling will be applied max means if the screen size is bigger than your number the styling in the media query will not be applied. Same with min if screen size is lower than your number styling will not be applied. Screen means that you styling will be applied when the medium has a screen for example you could write print than the styling will only be applied if you print your website.

Comment: could you vote to my question please ?

Answer (score 2):

The media-queries are basically a simple `if` statement on other programming languages.

**`screen`:** The `screen` is used to define the rules only for computer screens, tablets or smartphones. There are other media-types like `projection` or `print`.

**`max-width`:** specifies the maximum width of the screen (or media) for the CSS rules. All rules in this part are for screens lower and equals the value.

**`min-width`:** specifies the minimum width of the screen (or media) for the CSS rules. All rules in this part are for screens larger than the value.

**Example #1 (using `min-width`):**

`@media screen and (min-width: 456px) { ... }`

The CSS rules in this part are only used for computer screens, tablets or smartphones with a minimum screen width of 456 pixel.

**Example #2 (using `max-width`):**

`@media screen and (max-width: 456px) { ... }`

The CSS rules in this part are only used for computer screens, tablets or smartphones with a maximum screen width of 456 pixel.

> **CSS3 Media Queries:** https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Answer (score 2):

- A media queries detect media type which are currently using your
  website in this case is screen so any device - you can also put
  specific css for print - to make your website be print friendly.
  Using Media Queries are core of RWD - responsive web design.
- **min-width** its saying browser 'please use this block of css rules if viewport of your browser is min 312px so basicly every device
  which has viewport size bigger than 312px.
- **max-width** its saying please do this block of css rules if viewport of device is bigger than 456px - so all devices which has
  455px and less will not run this css rules.

There is also state like **@media screen and (min-width: 200px) and (max-width: 1000px) {}** - its targeting devices which has more than 201px and less than 999px of viewport size.

Links:

**https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/emailology_media_queries_demystified_min-width_and_max-width**

https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 1):

Most media features can be prefixed with "min-" or "max-" to express "greater or equal to" or "less than or equal to" constraints. This avoids using the "<" and ">" symbols, which would conflict with HTML and XML. If you use a media feature without specifying a value, the expression resolves to true if the feature's value is non-zero.

Hopefully this guide will help you understand how this works:  [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

You should also check out this guide to the different screen sizes: 
 [Link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)